# how to generate individual rows for each character between two delimiters in a string

Tags: sql-server

I have a data set with square brackets.

```
CREATE TABLE Testdata
(
    SomeID INT,
    String VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT Testdata SELECT 1,  'S0000X-T859XX[DEFGH]'
INSERT Testdata SELECT 1,   'T880XX-T889XX[DS]'
INSERT Testdata SELECT 2,  'V0001X-Y048XX[DS]'
INSERT Testdata SELECT 2,   'Y0801X-Y0889X[AB]'
```

i need to get output like below,

```
SomeId  String 
1       S0000XD-T859XXD
1       S0000XE-T859XXE
1       S0000XF-T859XXF
1       S0000XG-T859XXG
1       S0000XH-T859XXH
1       T880XXD-T889XXD
1       T880XXS-T889XXS
2       V0001XD-Y048XXD
2       V0001XS-Y048XXS
2       Y0801XA-Y0889XA
2       Y0801XB-Y0889XB
```

Appreciate if any one can help this

Comment: Replace is not work for me . Please see the output What I want.

Comment: You're wanting to enumerate the range in the brackets. You should explain that a little more clearly. We *want* to know what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I'm seeing this as more of a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a function here, and certainly no need for loops. A tally table will make short work of this. First you need a tally table. I keep one as a view on my system. It is nasty fast!!!

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

You don't have use a view like this, you could just use the CTEs directly in your code.

This is some rather ugly string manipulation but since your data is not properly normalized you are kind of stuck there. Please try this query. It produces what you said you expect as output.

```
select *
    , NewOutput = left(td.String, charindex('-', td.String) - 1) + SUBSTRING(td.String, CHARINDEX('[', td.String) + t.N, 1) + 
        left(substring(td.String, charindex('-', td.String), len(td.String)), charindex('[', substring(td.String, charindex('-', td.String), len(td.String))) - 1) + SUBSTRING(td.String, CHARINDEX('[', td.String) + t.N, 1)
from TestData td
join cteTally t on t.N <= CHARINDEX(']', td.String) - CHARINDEX('[', td.String) - 1
order by td.String
    , t.N
```

Comment: Cool. Make sure you understand it though so you can support it. I am happy to help you if there are part(s) you don't follow.

Comment: The idea of joining a tally table on the range of numbers equal to the length of the substring is sublime.  Nice work Sean.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this because I did it.

```
select distinct *
    ,[base]+substring(splitter,number,1)
from
(
select  SomeID
    -- split your column into a base plus a splitter column
    ,[base] = left(string,charindex('[',string)-1)
    ,splitter = substring(string, charindex('[',string)+1,len(string) - charindex('[',string)-1)


from
(
-- converted your insert into a union all
SELECT 1 SomeID,  'S0000X-T859XX[DEFGH]' string
union all
SELECT 1,   'T880XX-T889XX[DS]'
union all
SELECT 2,  'V0001X-Y048XX[DS]'
union all
SELECT 2,   'Y0801X-Y0889X[AB]'
) a
) inside
cross apply (Select number from master..spt_values where number>0 and number <=len(splitter)) b -- this is similar to a tally table using an internal SQL table
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include any attempt to solve this, I will assume that you are not stuck on any particular technique, and are looking for a high-level approach.

I would solve this by first creating a Table-valued function that takes the `id` and the `string` as parameters, and creates an output table by looping through the characters in between the square-brackets, so that the function's output looks like this

```
ID    String         Character
1     S0000X-T859XX  D
1     S0000X-T859XX  E
1     S0000X-T859XX  F
..
2     V0001XD-Y048XX D
etc...
```

Then you simply write a query that joins the raw table to the function on the `ID` and the portion of the `String` without the brackets.

Comment: Can you please explain how to create  Table-valued function  for  separate last character because I have no idea how t do this. I am sorry

Comment: I recommend `NGrams8k` @AnushaSubashini